# list matching patterns with awk

Tags: awk, filter, pattern-matching

I have a file containing patterns and messages separated by ":"

```
pattern1:First pattern
pattern12:Second pattern
pat1:Short pattern
pat12:Short pattern 2
```

If i run like this:

```
awk -F: '$1~/pat1/ {print $2}' file
```

it filters perfectly and gives output:

```
Short pattern
Short pattern 2
```

But actually I want to get messages of patterns which matching my provided string. Lets say i have a string `example string with pattern12 substring inside` i would expect to get:

```
First pattern
Second pattern
```

because two patterns in the file matching my string. Unfortunately nor

```
awk -F: '$1~/example string with pattern12 substring inside/ {print $2}' file
```

neither

```
awk -F: '"example string with pattern12 substring inside"~/$1/ {print $2}' file
```

works for me.

Is there a way to achieve this with these simple and beautiful filters without moving check inside awk program body?

Now I call a bash script and pass string as argument:

```
script.sh "example string with pattern12 substring inside"
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read pattern message
do
    grep -qe "$pattern" <<< $1 && break
done < fie
```

But i want to use `awk` instead of `grep` as it can filter multiple fields at once not only as pattern but arithmetically too: `pattern >= 256`

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in form of code, could you please more elaborate on your passing string thing, sorry but its not clear. Do you mean that you want to pass a string to `awk` and check that any field is matching with 1st field of Input_file or not? Kindly do add more information on same.

Comment: May be: `awk -F: -v s="example string with pattern12 substring inside" 'index(s, $1) {print $2}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
$ awk -F: '"example string with pattern12 substring inside"~$1 {print $2}' file
```

Output:

```
First pattern
Second pattern
```

If not, then what @RavinderSingh13 is asking above.